# trees for family tree creation

Tags: algorithm, tree, parent-child

I'm looking for a good algorithm to work out the lowest common ancestor for two people, without an initial overall tree.

If I have a child, I can make a call to get the parent. So if I have two children, I would need to make calls on each until they have a common ancestor. By this point I should have two lists, which I can build into a tree.

What kind of algorithm would be good for this?

Comment: well at the lowest common ancestor there are no other connections, so the "tree" would just be the two lists, one on the left, one on the right with the common ancestor as the root node...

Comment: Two questions to help clarify (for me) your case: 1. does a child have one or two parents (you talk about 'people'...)?; 2. do the items ("people") have an 'age'?

Comment: @BertteVelde a child has one parent and the items do not have an age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's some basic information that determines whether a specific node can "in principle" be the parent of another specific node, it would allow you to determine the common ancestor (if any) quickly/efficiently. That's what my question about "age" - see comment - was about.
An age-property obviously would give you that type of information.

Assuming, from your answer, that there's no such information available, there are two obvious approaches:

A. scan both trees upwards (getParent, etcetera), building for each initial child the ancestor list, meanwhile checking with every new ancestor whether it occurs in the other child's ancestor list. Generally speaking, there is no reason to assume that the common ancestor is at ("almost") equal distance from the two children, so any order in which you build the respective ancestor-lists is equally like to give you the common ancestor in the fewest possible steps.

A drawback of this method is that you run the risk of having to search in the mutual lists a large number of times for the occurrence of a new candidate. This is potentially slow.

B. an alternative is to simply build each of the two ancestorlists independently until exhaustion. This is probably relatively fast as you are not interrupted at each step by having to check the contents of "the other" list.

Then, when you've finished the two lists, you either have a common ancestor or not, simply by verifying the top-items against each other.
If no, you're done (no result). If yes, you walk back down the lists synchronously and check where they separate, again avoiding the list-search.

From a general point of view I'd prefer method B. Occasionally method A will of course produce the result faster, but in bad cases it may become tedious/slow, which will not happen with method B. I assume, of course, that any ancestorlist cannot be circular, i.e, that a node cannot be an ancestor of itself.

As a final note: IF, after all, you do have a property that "orders" nodes in the sense of "age", then you should build the two lists simultaneously, in the sense that you always process the list that has currently a top node which cannot possibly be the parent of the other list's topnode. This allows you to check only the current topnodes against each other (and not any other members of the lists).

Comment: There unfortunately isn't an order in the sense of age. All children will eventually report to the root node, my problem is to find the lowest common ancestor. Method B does seem good, thank you for your help.